# Magento Upgrading issue from 1.6 to 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, upgrade

Hi i am facing following issue while upgrading

> CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.7.0.1 conflicts
>   with: community/Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.3.2, community/Mage_All_Latest
>   1.7.0.2 Package community/Lib_Varien 1.7.0.0 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.6.0.0 Package community/Lib_Js_Mage
>   1.7.0.1 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.6.0.0 Package community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.7.0.1 conflicts with:
>   community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.6.0.0 Package community/Lib_Mage 1.7.0.1
>   conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.6.0.0

Please help me to fix this issue

Comment: try to increase php memory limit

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading via Magento Connect can be tricky and error messages cryptic.

The reason being that specific modules rely on other modules by a specific version. In the Connect package if the required module version is not installed or available for install then the error you're now receiving is triggered from within `Mage_Connect_Command_Install`.

The following are some methods to troubleshooting:

- Disable all caching - including memcached, APC
- Ensure that `var/package` is writable by the web user, delete current contents if necessary and errors persist.
- Run the [magento-check.php compatibility script](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento) and ensure that all required PHP extensions are installed, give the web user ownership (`chown`) of the entire web root (required for upgrade via Connect).
- [Reset all file permissions for your install](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions)
- Increase your memory_limit for PHP [to the minimum required 256MB RAM (preferably 512MB)](http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements)

If all else fails, you can always download the latest version and `cp -R` (Linux) or `ditto` the files over top of your install to upgrade.

Comment: @philwinkle. pls see this & i did not find any solution : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194959/how-can-we-connect-with-channel-connect-magentocommerce-com-core-to-upgrade-fr